# .Net Core euro currency symbol not show in RegionInfo

Tags: c#, .net, culture

I don't know if it could be a .net problem or something I need to configure. Tested in NET 5 & 6 with console app.
Any idea?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo culture1 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        Console.WriteLine("The current culture is {0} -> {1}", culture1.Name, culture1.DisplayName);
        CultureInfo uiCulture2 = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        Console.WriteLine("The current UI culture is {0} -> {1}\n", uiCulture2.Name, culture1.DisplayName);

        Console.WriteLine();

        RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo("ES");
        Console.WriteLine("   Name:                         {0}", myRI1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("   DisplayName:                  {0}", myRI1.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine("   EnglishName:                  {0}", myRI1.EnglishName);
        Console.WriteLine("   IsMetric:                     {0}", myRI1.IsMetric);
        Console.WriteLine("   ThreeLetterISORegionName:     {0}", myRI1.ThreeLetterISORegionName);
        Console.WriteLine("   ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: {0}", myRI1.ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName);
        Console.WriteLine("   TwoLetterISORegionName:       {0}", myRI1.TwoLetterISORegionName);
        Console.WriteLine("   CurrencySymbol:               {0}", myRI1.CurrencySymbol);
        Console.WriteLine("   ISOCurrencySymbol:            {0}", myRI1.ISOCurrencySymbol);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Return:

```
Name:                         ES
DisplayName:                  España
EnglishName:                  Spain
IsMetric:                     True
ThreeLetterISORegionName:     ESP
ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: ESP
TwoLetterISORegionName:       ES
CurrencySymbol:               ?    <= should be €
ISOCurrencySymbol:            EUR
```

Executed in computers with Win11 and Win10.
Others regions like GB, US, PK work fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Euro symbol. If there was, millions of developers *and users* would have noticed since 2001. The Regional info data comes from Windows directly. If there was such a problem all users in Europe would have noticed. Where did you display this output? Are you sure this isn't a font or console problem?

Comment: Try running your code in Windows Terminal. If you used the old Console ensure that `Unicode` is enabled in the console properties

Comment: Have a look at *string dump*: put `string.Join(" ", myRI1.CurrencySymbol.Select(c => $"{c} (\\u{(int)c:x4})"))` instead of `myRI1.CurrencySymbol`. Now you have a code of each character, e.g. `€ (\u20ac)`. If you have a correct code and wrong character, you should blame the font

Answer (score 1):

It was missing to put:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos